# Dock items reordered after unlock in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, dock

The opened programs in the dock are shuffled after unlocking the screen. I've noticed that after the items are ordered in a specific way after several **locks and unlocks**, they are not being shuffled anymore.

Is there any way to stop/disable this?

It happens on Ubuntu **20.04.1** with **GNOME** desktop environment.